# WordPress: get data from array in database

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, loops, serialization

I have custom fields that are created dynamicaly. I get the data from those fields and store it into a database as an array with `update_post_meta`. It's stored as a serialised array in the database:

```
a:4:{i:1;s:4:"1993";i:2;s:4:"1994";i:3;s:4:"1995";i:4;s:4:"1996";}
```

**Now I need to get this array and echo it out on the website, so it looks something like: 4 children (1993,1994,1995,1996).**

Here's the code I use now, but it doesn't work.

```
<?php
$children = get_post_custom_values('rbchildyear');

foreach ($children as $key => $value){
  echo "$key => $value('rbchildyear')<br>";
}
?>
```

And thats what I get in the front office:

```
0 => a:4:{i:1;s:4:"1993";i:2;s:4:"1994";i:3;s:4:"1995";i:4;s:4:"1996";}('rbchildyear')
```

**So how can I do that?**

Thank you!

Comment: what you are getting in $children ?

Comment: its an input text field with `name="rbchildyear[]"`.

Answer (score 2):

use unserialize().

```
$children = unserialize('a:4:{i:1;s:4:"1993";i:2;s:4:"1994";i:3;s:4:"1995";i:4;s:4:"1996";}');

print_r($children);
```

This will return array

Comment: there are get_post_meta() in WordPress that unserializes data and get_post_custom_values() that returns an array containing all the values, i need to use them somehow, just can't figure out what exactly im doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you use get_post_meta it will return an array of values (numerically indexed).  Then you can loop through the array with a foreach.

```
$childYears = get_post_meta($post_id, "rbchildyear", true);

foreach($childYears AS $theYear)
{
     $printThis .= $theYear.",";
}

print count($childYears)." children ( ".$printThis." )";
```